# USB Diskdrive cannot be formatted nor accessed

Tags: usb, formatting

So I have just recently bought and 8GB USB stick(Kingston DT 100 G2) on which I had installed Linux. However I needed to reinstall said Linux so I formatted the stick to "default" settings which includes FAT32 filesystem.

Later when the install process kept getting errors, I got advice that the problem might be with the FAT filesystem. I decided to try and format the stick to NTSF (format G:/fs:ntsf) but the formatting failed and the drive broke down.

And with breaking down I mean you cannot access the drive anymore and when you plug it in Windows asks if I want to format the drive but despite my will the format always fails.

To fix this I tried changing it back to FAT32 (format G:/fs:fat32), but i get "Error in IOCTL-call". Second thing I tried was trying to reset the filesystem with some 3rd party application like HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool. But the programs didn´t regocnize any media on the drive.

So now I´m in the situation that I haven´t got any idea on what to do next. Is the drive recoverable or did I just create a piece of waste metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to disk management under the device manager in Windows.  Does the USB stick show up?  If so, try removing the partition, then create a new one.

If that doesnt work, try creating and booting off a Gnome Partition Editor [livecd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to erase/format the disk.  It may be able to accomplish more than Windows disk management is able to.

Comment: Yeah it seems it´s fried. Went to the device manager and it just showed a grey bar where the partitions should´ve been. And when i got the Gparted it didn´t even regocnize the stick. So I quess i´ll have to buy a new one.

Comment: try Gnome Partition Editor, you have nothing to lose

Comment: Yea I tried that but, as I edited to my earlier post, it didn´t even regocnize the stick.